# Use linux crontab in j2ee app

Tags: cron

I have been using [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) for over a year to schedule jobs in my app.  I now have a new requirement to get rid of quarts, and instead use crontab.  I have no experience in this area. How do I design something in my app that allows a job to be called by the operating system? Do I need to create a URL for each job that the OS can call?

Answer (score 0):

you could define simple rest or soap services (using [apache-cxf](http://cxf.apache.org/) or [axis2](http://ws.apache.org/axis2/) for example) and call the from a ruby- or pythonscript

Answer (score 0):

My company makes CloudQuartz ([www.thecloudblocks.com](http://www.thecloudblocks.com)) which allows you to schedule the jobs through an API and get callbacks when they are due to run.

It might be useful to what you're trying to do.